# SP - Package directory is missing from my Visual WebPart Solution

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, solution-package

How to resolve package directory ?

**Error is this:**

```
Error   1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**I'try to paste this  in CSPROJ File in my solution :**

```
<None Include="Package\Package.package">
  <PackageId>{GUID Of my Solution}</PackageId>
</None>
```

but error is tha same.. Please help me